# Retrieve Logs of Another region API

Tags: api, twilio, twilio-api

I am composing a script in phyton to get the monthly call logs.

I have an account whose main region is USA but the region in use is Ireland.

When I enter the account_sid and auth_token of the region I want to query (ireland) I get a credentials error, however, if I put the US credentials, the script works correctly but as it is logical, without any call log.

It is worth mentioning that in the script composition, I am using as base url api.dublin.ie1.twilio.com.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Same as the previous box

Comment: If it's solved, mark the correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need a create an [API key for your region](https://www.twilio.com/docs/global-infrastructure/create-an-outbound-call-via-rest-api-in-a-non-us-twilio-region) (i.e. Ireland) to connect to the local API endpoint.

Here's an example in Node.js that should work:

```js
const accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID;
const apiKeySid = process.env.API_KEY_SID;
const apiKeySecret = process.env.API_KEY_SECRET;

const toNumber = process.env.TO_NUMBER;
const fromNumber = process.env.FROM_NUMBER;

const client = require('twilio')(
    apiKeySid,
    apiKeySecret, {
        accountSid: accountSid,
        edge: 'dublin',
        region: 'ie1'
    });

client.calls.list({}).then(function(list){
  console.log(list)
});
```

Comment: Good morning.

I have converted the code to python, but I am having credentials problems, I have opened a ticket with twilio support, to verify where the problem is in the credentials since I use the ones from the console itself.

Thank you very much for the answer.

Best regards.